# XML body of HTML response is "0"?

Tags: java, xml, http, tcp

I am trying to send an HTTP request in order to get a response (TCP-IP) , which should contain XML . Here is the method I am using for sending a request and returning it :

```
public String getResponse() throws IOException {
    String result="";
    Socket socket = new Socket(host,port);

    //encoding login and password
    String username = "root";
    String password = "ut72";
    String auth = username + ":" + password;
    String encodedAuth = Base64.encode(auth.getBytes());

    //sending request
    PrintWriter request = new PrintWriter( socket.getOutputStream() );
    request.print(  "GET " + path + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
            "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
            "Authorization: Basic " + encodedAuth + "\r\n" +
            "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
    request.flush( );

    //waiting for response
    InputStream inStream = socket.getInputStream( );
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(inStream));
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result = result+"\n"+line;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here is my main :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
    GetDataFromUnidrive getter = new GetDataFromUnidrive("http://192.168.130.182/US/4.02/dynamic/readparval.xml");
    String response = getter.getResponse();
    System.out.println(response);
```

Here is the response I get :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml
Cache-Control: private
Expires: Thu, 26 Oct 1995 00:00:00 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Allegro-Software-RomPager/4.01
Connection: close

0


Process finished with exit code 0
```

If I am guessing right, the "0" in the middle is the XML response . But ... this is NOT what I should get ; indeed, If I am typing my request in a browser, typing "http://192.168.130.182/US/4.02/dynamic/readparval.xml", I am getting this (this what I want to obtain with my program) :

[image: xml I should have]

Can somebody explain me reasons which could make this "0" appear ?

**EDIT :** Here is what I am doing with HttpClient (the same things seem to occur)

```
    String url = "http://192.168.130.182/US/4.02/dynamic/readparval.xml";

    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

    System.out.println("Response Code : "
            + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    String result = "";
    String line = "";
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result+=line;
    }
    return result;
```

This gives me the result :

```
Response Code : 200


Process finished with exit code 0
```

When I am trying to have more information...(I'm doing String result = response.getEntity().toString();) I am getting this :

```
Response Code : 200
ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: text/xml,Chunked: true]}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

So I guess I am still getting the chuncked tranfert-enconding anyway ...

Comment: Is there any reason why you writing HTTP client by yourself? Why not use HTTP Client build in java rt?

Comment: The only reason is that I just wanted to experiment to do it in this way ; anyway I tried to do the same thing with java HTTPClient, but got the same result . Do you know what could cause this "0" to be displayed ?

Comment: Ah, Ok. For learning its fine I guess but you should never write such code to use in your app if libs exists. Its 0 because response data are chunked - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding . With java HTTPClient it should be fine, are you sure?

Comment: I guess so . I edited my post so that you can see what I did using HttpClient . Hopefully you'll see what's wrong .

Comment: Well then simplest explanation is, server returns 0 length content. Does it work in browser? Check if your browser sending different request

Comment: The requests are the same...Could it be possible that I cannot read the result because it is chuncked ?